# What is the equivalent of @RuleChain in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

- I have 2 "class level" rules : `MyRule1` and `MyRule2`
- `MyRule2` depends on `MyRule1`
- `MyRule1` "before" method should therefore run before the `MyRule2` "before" method.

In JUnit 4, it can be implemented this way, via the [RuleChain](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) :

```
static MyRule1 myRule1 = new MyRule1();
static MyRule2 myRule2 = new MyRule2(myRule1);

@Rule
TestRule ruleChain = RuleChain.outerRule(myRule1)
        .around(myRule2);
```

In JUnit 5, I have to implement it this way :

```
static MyRule1 myRule1 = new MyRule1();

@RegisterExtension
static MyRule2 myRule2 = new MyRule2(myRule1);
```

with `MyRule2` :

```
class MyRule2 implements BeforeAllCallback {

    private final MyRule1 myRule1;

    public MyRule2(MyRule1 myRule1) {
        this.myRule1 = myRule1;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        this.myRule1.beforeAll();

        X x = this.myRule1.getX();
        // do Rule 2 stuff with x
    }
}
```

It's the equivalent of the JUnit 4 implementation when it comes to the result.

But I have to explicitly and manually call the `beforeAll()` callback of `MyRule1` in `MyRule2`.

I would like that `MyRule2` would not be responsible for `MyRule1` execution.

I went through the [Extension Model documentation of JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions)
but didn't find anything on extensions that depend on other extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extensions registered via `@RegisterExtension`, there is currently (as of JUnit Jupiter 5.3.1) no built-in support analogous to JUnit 4's `RuleChain`.

However, [this issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/506) links to a custom solution and also proposes support for `@Order` to control the order in which extensions are executed.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [Jupiter's documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative):

> Extensions registered declaratively via `@ExtendWith` will be executed in the order in which they are declared in the source code.

So, in your case, you should just declare them in that order:

```
@ExtendsWith({Rule1.class, Rule2.class})
public class MyTest {
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain that I needed to access MyRule1 to do something in MyRule2. I updated my question. However if I do what you're suggesting, will JUnit5 inject Rule1 into Rule 2 ? I doubt it.

Comment: I'd be curious to know the answer to that too, because we have a similar situation where some of the rules are dependent on the other rules. (Most commonly, TempFolder.)

Answer (score 0):

For extensions registered via @RegisterExtension, some libraries as [testy-box](https://github.com/Marthym/testy-box#chainedextension) provide a support for Chained Extensions.